# MSE welcomes its $100\,000^{th}$ user...

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, celebration

Math.Stackexchange.com welcomes its [$100\,000^{\text{th}}$ user](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/100000/golovach-lena).
I don't think you'll get cookies, but even better you'll get your questions answered.

Comment: welcome!! @GolovachLena

Comment: Seems to me like a good addition to the [milestones page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/7021/history-of-math-stackexchange).

Comment: Well, if there is a user with number 100000, this does not exactly mean that MSE has 100000 users. Merged accounts, deleted users, probably other things,.... (But it definitely is a close approximation.)

Comment: @Martin: Also the user number includes unregistered accounts.

Comment: Over 100000 as of [January 22, 2014](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/170684/users-created-by-given-date?Date=2014-01-22); added to the history thread.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looking at the UserId is a serious overestimate. The [query](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/142845/number-of-users)

```
SELECT COUNT(Id) AS NumberOfUsers FROM Users
```

returns `82335`, based on the data from October 13. (This includes both registered and unregistered accounts.)

Since September 1, new users are joining at the rate of about 180/day, see [new users per day](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/80302/new-users-per-day). If this continues, the user base will reach 100000 in about 3 months.

The most up-to-date available count of users (also including unregistered) is in the [list of SE sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#science-questions) (link pointed out by Martin Sleziak). Mouse over the number of users to get a more precise figure.

---

The older version of this post used

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumberOfUsers FROM Users
```

which undercounts table rows by a thousand or so, for reasons that transcend my limited knowledge of SQL.

Comment: And as I type this it’s down to $81117$.

Comment: BTW number of the users is shown in the [list of sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#science-questions) in SE network, too. (I am not sure how often it is updated.) This number says 82848 at the moment.

Comment: @MartinSleziak The site list at stackexchange.com is updated at least daily, so it may be the best approximation to the current number of users. It's at `82904` now.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks for pointing out the drop; this was certainly an SQL artifact rather than an actual drop in the number of users. I modified the query to obtain a hopefully correct count.

Comment: 98766 users as of my writing this.

Answer (score 29):

... and closes her* post as off-topic.

> This question is missing context or other details

- assuming the name is real, which I doubt.

> Golovach Lena => Головач Лена  =>  "голова члена" => "head of the penis". An old old joke.

Comment: seems like reason to celebrate.....

Comment: Classic. ${}{} $

Comment: Very ironic....

Comment: And every comment ends with " Golovach Lena is Love!!!"...

Comment: @T.Bongers Hmm, is seems that the comments have been edited to remove the phrase.

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out, these kind of ID numbers (usually surrogate database keys) should not be used to count table rows, even disregarding deleted/merged accounts. Databases often produce "holes" in the sequence, (and that's considered ok) because of the need to deal with concurrency and transactions.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404244/values-missing-in-postgres-serial-field/3405490#3405490

http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/77/posts/19500/0267-sql-server-identity-columns-myths-identity-columns-cannot-have-holes-or-gaps.aspx